# Adding Programmable Search through Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is there a way to add the following script, required by Google Programmable Search to Google Tag Manager? Just trying to minimize separate scripts included in my code.

```
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=e14513e5d62xxxxxx"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

NM, figured it out. In case someone cares, here's how you do it:

1. Keep the code part where you want to include your search in the page code.
2. The above script can be added to GTM via Custom HTML tag. Just drop it there and it's done.

Cheers